# Activating virtual environment throws error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using Windows PowerShell. But, I don't know why, when I try to activate a python virtual environment, I get this error:

```
venv\Scripts\activate : File C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\flask\microblog\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see    
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

This is the command I ran:

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

This is the first time it has happened. What is the problem?

Comment: In PowerShell on Windows, script execution is disabled by default. Enable it with [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy). There are 3 scopes; more specific ones have higher precedence: `-Scope LocalMachine` (requires admin rights), `-Scope CurrentUser`, or `-Scope Process` (current process only). The PowerShell CLI accepts a process-specific `-ExecutionPolicy <policy>` too . Execution policies can also be set via GPO, in which case they cannot be changed or overridden with `Set-ExecutionPolicy` or via the CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like running powershell scripts is disabled on your machine.
you can run as admin:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

this should solve the problem

Comment: That works, but you don't necessarily need admin privileges, namely if you use `-Scope CurrentUser`. Conversely, if the execution policy is set via GPO (Group Policy Objects), it can't be changed with `Set-ExecutionPolicy`.